# Chrome extension that automatically re-download when interrupted?

Tags: google-chrome, download, automation, google-chrome-extensions

Is there such a thing or can any other browsers have this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that add-on DownThemAll! on firefox could automatic retry download when interrupted. And there are options to change retry times and intervals. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's download manager really sucks and there is no way to restart the interrupted download, if you are in Linux however, you can use wget to resume downloads. just rename the file, it has .crdownload appended to it to the actual name of the file.

> wget -c (URL)

Answer (score 1):

Well addition to answer by HackToHell,
Have a download.sh script like below, which will retry downloading each and everytime network breaks, from where it was left previously.

```
#!/bin/bash

link=$1

if [ "$link" == "" ]; then
    echo "Provide valid download link";
    exit -1;
fi

while(true)
do
        wget -c $link

        retval="$?"
        if [ $retval -eq 0 ]; then
                break;
        fi
done
```

And call it link

```
$./download.sh DOWNLOAD_LINK
```

If you want your download to continue after you exit from shell then

```
$nohup ./download.sh DOWNLOAD_LINK > nohup.out &
disown
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Chrome, but Firefox's [Download StatusBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-statusbar/) let's you pause and resume downloads with a single click.  Once the download starts, it'll show in the status bar on the bottom of the screen, then if your connection gets interrupted, just click it twice (but not double click!).  It'll attempt to resume automatically.

You can also click just once on it to pause.

EDIT: pausing and resuming a download in chrome should have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome users, [I've found this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-resume-downloads/pifbhionjpacnpjoaomhdpbekkdphdgd/related?hl=en-US) to be one of the most up-to-date (at the time of writing) ways to solve resume failed downloads.